# C++ class extension (different size of array in inheriting classes)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to C++, i would like to get an advice.
I am writing two classes that contain both an array of the same object but with different size. Both of the classes has the same methods to deal with the array, but each has it's own unique behavior. Because of that, i would like to create a new class to represent the array and the operations on it, and to make these two classes extend it.

For example:

```
Class classA{
     Person* persons[5];
     string className;
     ...
}

Class classB{
     Person* persons[15];
     int integerForClassB;
     string className;
     ...
}
```

What is the best (most suggested) way to define the class parentClass such that it will deal only with the pesrons array and that classA will extend parentClass (with array of size 5) and classB will extend parentClass (with array of size 15)?

Comment: Eh, [`std::vector<Person>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)...

Comment: Additionally, Person* persons[5] does not mean you're declaring an array of 5 persons.

Comment: Eh, `std::vector<Person*>`...

Comment: Eh, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this help? Using an STL vector of type Person, you can make the base class take a count for the number of persons. Then each derived class calls the base class constructor with a different size for the m_persons vector. The vector in each case will then be filled to the requested size with default-initialised instances of Person.

## include

```
class Person
{
};

class ParentClass
{
public:
    // Relies on Person having a default constructor
    ParentClass( int personCount ) : m_persons( personCount )
    {
    } 
    
private:
    std::vector<Person> m_persons;
};

class ClassA : public ParentClass
{
public:
    ClassA() : ParentClass(5)
    {
    }
};

class ClassB : public ParentClass
{
public:
    ClassB() : ParentClass(15)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: ClassA and ClassB will be sliced when you copy them to vector<Persion> it must be either vector of pointers or a smart-pointer wrappers

Comment: @alexm: ClassA and ClassB are not inherited from Person, but from ParentClass. Person is a single class, not part of a hiearchy. Slicing is not an issue here.

Comment: For what it is worth, if you use `vector::reserve` in the constructor body instead of using the value-initializing vector constructor, then you can remove the requirement that `Person` must have a default constructor.  In both cases, `Person` must have a copy-constructor.

Comment: @twansbury: Reserve won't give you N instances, just the space for N instances. I guess that's your point - as then you don't need the default ctor as you're not constructing anything. But I'm not sure that fits my interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to extend the array handling class? Maybe it is better to just use that class from ClassA and ClassB. [Prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Do you need an array? As others have said a std::vector could be better.

In case you need the array, have you thought on using templates? A class template can have integer arguments like

```
template <int npersons> class PersonHandler {
    Person* persons[npersons]
}
```

so you can inherit ClassA from PersonHandler<5> and ClassB from PersonHandler<15>. But note that the PersonClass is a different class for ClassA and ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, my thought is that the *best* way is to not use inheritance.  Use `public` inheritance to define a class hierarchy.  Be very cautious when using it as a means of code reuse, as more often than not, composition is the superior option.

- As suggested in the comments, consider a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
- If `std::vector` does not have all of the desired operations, check if [`<algorithms>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) fulfills your needs.
- If your needs are still not fulfilled, consider writing collection operations as free functions instead of member functions.  With proper decoupling, these operations can work on `std::vector<Person>` or arrays of `Person`.
- If you must have a collection of `Persons` with very specific behavior, then use composition.  The question description implies composition is correct: "two classes that *contain* both an array..."

With regards to inheritance, if `classA` is-a collection-of`Persons` and `classB` is-a collection-of`Persons`, then consider `public` inheritance, if the set of common methods, that different in behavior, can uphold a common set of pre-conditions and post-conditions.  For example, consider an `Ellipse` and `Circle`:

```
class Ellipse
{
  // Set the width of the shape.
  virtual void width( unsigned int );

  // Set the height of the shape.
  virtual void height( unsigned int );
};

class Circle
{
  // Set the width of the shape.  If height is not the same as width, then
  // set height to be equal to width.
  virtual void width( unsigned int );

  // Set the height of the shape.  If width is not the same as height, then
  // set width to be equal to height.
  virtual void height( unsigned int );
};
```

It is very tempting to have `Circle` derive from `Ellipse`:

- Outside of programming, one could argue that `Circle` is a special kind of `Ellipse`, just like a `Square` is a special kind of `Rectangle`.
- They even have the same member functions: `width()` and `height()`.

However, do not do it!  `Ellipse` can do things a `Circle` cannot do, such as having a different width and height; therefore `Circle` should not be a kind of `Ellipse`.